# (AWS) Getting RDS state via Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I've been trying to retrieve the state of an RDS instance via Lambda in RDS, and I keep coming up short because I can't parse the response. I know I'm totally missing something here that's obvious. Here is the code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var rdsparams = {
  DBInstanceIdentifier: 'mysql1'
};
module.exports = (instanceId) => {
 var rds = new AWS.RDS();
 var params = {
  DBInstanceIdentifier: instanceId
};
var rdsResponse = rds.describeDBInstances(rdsparams, function (err, 
 data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);           // successful response
  });

var resultData = {};
rds.describeDBInstances(rdsparams, function(err, data) {
  if (err)
    return context.done(err, null);

  var rdsarray = {};
  var rdsarray = (data);
  console.log(rdsarray);
  var ins = rdsarray[0];
  console.log("Status: " + ins.DBInstanceStatus);

});
};
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'DBInstanceStatus' of undefined
    at Response.

Comment: (at this line console.log("Status: " + ins.DBInstanceStatus);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on with your code there!

The specific problem is that `data` isn't an array. Take a look at the response from the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#describeDBInstances-property

The array of returned values is in `data.DBInstances`. So those last few lines might be:

```
  var rdsarray = data.DBInstances;
  console.log(rdsarray);
  var ins = rdsarray[0];
  console.log("Status: " + ins.DBInstanceStatus);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something simple like this... Like you said, too much going on in there - that was probably my main problem!